# In Python, If we import inside a function, are we still able to use that import outside of function code or if the function is not called?

Tags: python, function, import

If we were to import inside of a function, can we still use that import outside of the function code without importing again or if the function is not called? Why or Why not?
How does importing at the beginning outside the function code vs importing inside of the function code work?

I have 2 examples here:

1)

```
def compute(rad,num):
    import random as rd
```

vs

2)

```
import random as rd
def compute(rad,num):
```

For the 1st example, am I able to use the import random outside of the function code later on without importing random again? Am I able to use the import random if that function in not called without importing random again? How does importing outside vs importing inside a function works and what are the differences. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try it?  What did you find?  What did you understand (or not) about the results?

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to use imported modules outside the function inside which they are imported.

In your first example, `rd` is only bound within the scope of the function and disappears when the function exits, whereas in your second example, `rd` is valid within the scope of the entire module containing the function `compute()`

Visit https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import for more info (in particular the second step: define a name or names in the local namespace for the scope where the import statement occurs.)

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you forget the fact that `rd` was created via an `import` statement, and focus on understanding the scope of that variable in each case.

```
x = 42

def compute(rad,num):
    print(x)  # works
```

In this example, `x` is bound in the global scope, and it's accessible from inner scopes as well (as long as they don't shadow it with another `x` within that scope).

```
def compute(rad,num):
    x = 42
    print(x)  # works

print(x)  # doesn't work
```

In this example, `x` is only bound in the inner scope.  Code in the global scope can't see it.

When you do:

```
import random as rd
```

you can almost think of it as doing:

```
import random
rd = random
```

You're just binding a variable called `rd` to reference the `random` module.  If you do that inside a function, it's only available in that function.  If you do it outside of any function, the binding is in the global scope and it's available to everything else in that module.